# ggplot2 - Survival Swimmer Plot Not Displaying Sorted Values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131184/swimmer-survival-plot) question I've been assembling a customized Swimmer Plot, but despite my having sorted the patients by Therapy.Length, when I try to plot it the second half of the bars often come out much longer than they should be - putting the graph out of order.

[image: The Swimmer Plot with incorrect bar lengths]

I've checked and the symbols are in the correct place even when the bar is too long, so somehow the bar lengths are getting extended. By commenting out `scale_y_continuous` chunk, I'm able to get the proper length on the bars, but then all of the symbol placement is compressed.

```
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(Patient.ID, Therapy.Length)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=factor(Disease.Stage)), width=0.7) +
  geom_point(data=dat,  aes(Patient.ID, value, colour=variable, shape=variable), size=4) +
  geom_segment(data=dat %>% filter(Continued == 1),
               aes(x=Patient.ID, xend=Patient.ID, y=Therapy.Length + 0.1, yend=Therapy.Length + 20),
               arrow=arrow(type="closed", length=unit(0.13,"in"))) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=5)[1:4],100,70)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=3)[1:2],100,40),c("black","darkgreen"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,max(dat$Therapy.Length)), breaks=seq(0,max(dat$Therapy.Length),30)) +
  labs(fill="Disease Stage", colour="", shape="", x="Subject Received Study Drug") 
+ theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

Here's the rest of the code: [[x]](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MatthewWolff/Scraps/master/OngResearch.r)

**ANSWER:**
`dat` had originally been melted – changed `dat` to be unmelted (and created `dat.m` to be the melted version), and supplied `dat.m`to `geom_point` and `geom_segment` for adding points to bars.

data:

```
structure(list(Patient.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("13", 
"5", "14", "11", "6", "2", "7", "12", "3", "8", "1", "10", "4", 
"15", "9"), class = "factor"), Disease.Stage = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), Response.Start = c(15, 40, 
51, 26, 36, 26, 32, 43, 67, 80, 93, 105, 160, 34, 94, 15, 40, 
51, 26, 36, 26, 32, 43, 67, 80, 93, 105, 160, 34, 94, 15, 40, 
51, 26, 36, 26, 32, 43, 67, 80, 93, 105, 160, 34, 94, 15, 40, 
51, 26, 36, 26, 32, 43, 67, 80, 93, 105, 160, 34, 94), Therapy.Length = c(74, 
84, 84, 108, 128, 185, 194, 198, 257, 274, 293, 311, 325, 336, 
357, 74, 84, 84, 108, 128, 185, 194, 198, 257, 274, 293, 311, 
325, 336, 357, 74, 84, 84, 108, 128, 185, 194, 198, 257, 274, 
293, 311, 325, 336, 357, 74, 84, 84, 108, 128, 185, 194, 198, 
257, 274, 293, 311, 325, 336, 357), Continued = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 
1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 
1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
NA, 1), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Response.End", "Durable", "Complete", 
"Partial"), class = "factor"), value = c(40, 78, 78, 106, 89, 
177, 108, 101, 138, 209, 279, 244, 311, 167, 271, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 32, 43, NA, NA, 93, NA, 160, NA, 94, 15, NA, 51, 26, 
36, 26, NA, NA, 67, 80, NA, 105, NA, 34, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), .Names = c("Patient.ID", "Disease.Stage", "Response.Start", 
"Therapy.Length", "Continued", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does setting the axis limits inside `coord_flip`, i.e., `coord_flip(ylim=c(-1,max(dat$Therapy.Length))`, (instead of inside `scale_y_continuous`) solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not – it scales the bars off the plot.

Comment: Then set `ylim` to include the full range of the bars.

Comment: @eipi10 I don't understand what you mean. After supplying the `ylim` inside of `coord_flip` instead of `scale_y_continuous`, the symbols are correctly being displayed (excellent) – but since the bars represent `Therapy.Length` and I've set  `ylim` to go from -1 to `max(dat$Therapy.Length)`, what should I change `ylim` to? Thank you in advance

Comment: You said that the bars are extending beyond the plot area (although, I'm not sure how that's happening if `max(dat$Therapy.Length)` is the highest bar value). So set the highest value of `ylim` to, say, `max(dat$Therapy.Length) + 100` or whatever increase is large enough to include the longest bar.

Comment: FYI, you can still use `scale_y_continuous` to set the breaks.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide your data so that we can run your code. Paste into your question the output of `dput(dat)`.

Comment: @eipi10 I greatly appreciate your time! I included a github link to all of the code. I set the seed at 1996 so it should be generating the same data each time. I'll also include the output from dput.

Comment: In the code you give to make your datasets, you end up with multiple observations per `PatientID` and `Disease.Stage` because of `variable`. Each ID/Stage has 4 observations, so due to stacking your longest bar is 1428, not 357.  Changing the limits removes the stacks that don't "fit" in the limits, making your bars look out of order.

Comment: If you remove the rows of `NA` in `value` prior to plotting I think you're almost there.  However, `PatientID` `1` still has 2 rows due to a possibly odd-looking `Durable` row where `value == -1`.

Comment: @aosmith You're right!! I changed the first parameter of `ggplot()` back to the data before i melted it, and supplied the melted data only to `geom_point` and `geom_segment`. Thank you so much, it's fixed